# UITableViewCell Subclass?

Tags: ios, uitableview, subclass

If I'm subclassing a `UITableViewCell`, is it better practice to actually write out a subclass or use the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and add my subviews to the default `UITableViewCell contentView`?

Comment: If using storyboards, I think a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass in conjunction with cell prototypes is the way to go. Incredibly easy to do, gets you out of creating the controls yourself, but you have a nice cell subclass that encapsulates your `IBOutlet` references.

Comment: I'm not using storyboards, they always seem to overcomplicate things; I've developed a habit of laying things out very generally on the `.xib` and then building my own hierarchy and custom views in code.

Comment: Fair enough. NIBs require you to write more code. But if that's the environment you're most comfortable with, go for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think choosing between subclassing and adding subviews to contentView depends on just how much you'd like to customize your cells. If you simply want to add a couple of additional subviews the second method is probably fine. If you want to get fancy and create custom animation for setSelected:animated:, setHighlighted:animated:, and setEditing:animated: you will obviously have to subclass. This subject is covered in Apple's documentation here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1

Also, tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called no matter which technique you use to customize your cell.

Comment: I'm writing a `UIView` containing a `UITableView`, and I'm pretty much trying to put a circular `UIImageView` on the right side with a `UILabel` on the left. I'm trying to avoid using storyboards and just use the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to drop them in. It doesn't look like the standard styles will suffice

Comment: In that case you might be able to easily get away without subclassing. There is already a UILabel available (textLabel) and you can set the accessoryView to a UIImageView. Take a look at the accessoryView property here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938

Answer (score 1):

It depends,

If you are not going to reuse that cell in any other table you might want to customize it in your `UITableViewController` subclass. However is still not a good practice because you might do changes in more delegate methods, such as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

If you are going to reuse that cell, you should subclass `UITableViewCell`.

For static views (a few and well known elements of the list), with many different heterogenous elements (such as a settings grouped menu) it can be easier (or faster) to do the customization in the `UITableViewController`, instead of subclassing many different styles of cells.